# Did hundreds of birds die in a park the Netherlands? What caused it?

Tags: biology, radiation, netherlands

> About a week ago at The Hague, many birds died spontaneously, falling
>   dead in a park. You likely haven’t heard a lot about this because it
>   seems keeping it quiet was the plan all along. However, when about 150
>   more suddenly died- bringing the death toll to 297- some started to
>   take notice.
>
> And if you are looking around that park you might have seen what is on
>   the corner of the roof across the street from where they died: a new
>   5G mast, where they had done a test, in connection with the Dutch
>   railway station, to see how large the range was and whether no harmful
>   equipment [sic] would occur on and around the station.
>
> And harm happened, indeed. Immediately afterward, birds fell dead from
>   the trees. And the nearby ducks that were swimming seemed to react
>   very oddly as well; they were simultaneously putting their heads
>   underwater to escape the radiation while others flew away, landing on
>   the street or in the canal.
>
> Again, almost at the exact same time that those animals died, near the
>   station, Holland Spoor was tested with a 5G transmitter mast.
>
> The birds that fell massively dead would be the victims of an
>   experiment, performed on those days in The Hague, where RF radiation
>   was tested with a peak frequency of 7.40 GHz, which corresponds to a
>   wavelength of 4.05 cm. This wavelength is of the same order of
>   magnitude as the size of the starlings. This may be important because
>   of possible resonance effects. The mast in question is about 400
>   meters from where the starlings have fallen dead. This information
>   comes from one source and should still be confirmed, if possible.

https://www.healthnutnews.com/hundreds-of-birds-dead-during-5g-experiment-in-the-hague-the-netherlands/

1. Is it true that hundreds of birds have died in this park?
2. If it is true, has a cause been positively determined?

Comment: Rewrote the question to avoid jumping to conclusions and to start with basic fact-checking instead of assuming some claims on which the question hinges are true.

Comment: *putting their heads underwater*, that's normal duck behaviour, they are feeding...

Comment: Is there any confirmation that there were tests of 5G nearby? Or what frequency was tested (note that 7.4GHz is NOT a standard frequency in the proposed 5G standards in Europe or anywhere else).

Comment: isn't the wavelength "being the size of birds" part absolute non-sense ?

Comment: See also: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/42740/do-fireworks-kills-birds-dogs-and-other-animals

Comment: @GlorfSf (pretty much) all the conspiracy theories around 5G are nonsense. There's a persistent one in the Netherlands that 5G is a mind control system for the illuminati/NWO/Jews/UN/EU/<name your favourite boogeyman of the day here>. This one may well be related to that.

Comment: @GlorfSf The wavelengths being the size of birds might be relevant if the birds are made of or coated in metal...

Comment: Actually, the wavelength of the radio signal being about the size of the bird could result in *resonance* in the bird, increasing the effective intensity of the signal.  Not likely to be a significant factor, however, and there are a lot of muddling factors involved.

Comment: I'll note that such unexplained bird kills are not that unusual -- one reads about them several times a year in the US (though perhaps not as massive as this one).  Fish kills are even more common.

Comment: @gerrit - not if they quack the Dutch equivalent of "oh... damn!" before submerging their heads.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - fish kills are usually very quickly and easily explained, though, compared to bird kills.

Comment: I recall the case of some sea birds who flew through the smoke stack effluent of an incinerator that the Feds were using to burn contraband marijuana.  A college professor got wind of this and decided to investigate the effect of the smoke on the birds.  After extensive research he determined that there was not a tern left unstoned.

Comment: This is perfect material for the conspiracy theorists at BirdsArentReal.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems to be true about a large number of suddenly dead birds.  There are some articles in Dutch media reporting this. However the cause has not been determined and there is no mention of 5G antennas in reports.

- [Mysterie rond dode vogels](https://www.telegraaf.nl/nieuws/2728050/mysterie-rond-dode-vogels) ("Mystery around dead birds")
- [Tientallen spreeuwen in Huijgenspark Den Haag sterven mysterieuze dood](https://www.hartvannederland.nl/nieuws/2018/tientallen-spreeuwen-huijgenspark-den-haag-sterven-mysterieuze-dood/) ("Dozens of starlings in Huijgenspark Den Haag die mysterious death")
- [Meer dan honderd vogels vallen dood uit bomen in Den Haag](http://www.welingelichtekringen.nl/natuur-en-milieu/856949/meer-dan-honderd-vogels-vallen-dood-uit-bomen-in-den-haag.html) ("More than a hundred birds fall dead from trees in The Hague")
- [Mysterieuze vogelsterfte in Den Haag: dode spreeuwen vallen massaal uit de lucht](https://www.rtlnieuws.nl/nieuws/artikel/4464101/mysterieuze-vogelsterfte-den-haag-dode-spreeuwen-vallen-massaal-uit-de-lucht) ("Mysterious bird deaths in The Hague: dead starlings fall massively from the sky")

Here is the Google translation of the article under the last link:

> For several days in a row, dead starlings fall from the sky in the
> Huijgenspark in The Hague. It is estimated that around 150 birds have
> already lost their lives. What is the cause of this is being
> investigated.
>
> The Dutch Food and Consumer Product Safety Authority, the Dutch
> Wildlife Health Center and a Wageningen University laboratory are
> investigating the cause of death of the starlings. A veterinarian of
> bird care De Wulp performed a number of birds last week. She only
> found internal bleeding and no trace of poison.
>
> **Contaminated water**
>
> "Last year we had the same situation at the Haagse Hogeschool, where
> it was renovated at the time", says an employee of the Animal
> Ambulance. "Then dozens of dead jackdaws were found, which probably
> had been poisoned because they had been drinking contaminated
> water. What's the matter now is really speculation, hopefully we'll
> know more next week, because this is not normal."
> Last Friday, the first reports of dead starlings arrived at the Haagse
> Dierenambulance. On arrival at the scene of the disaster exactly
> thirty starlings were found. They had fallen dead from a tree.
> Yesterday there were even more than ninety starlings in the park.
>
> **Sick dogs**
>
> According to hikers who put their dog on the spot, their animals also
> became ill afterwards. Dogs had to vomit and had problems with the
> stool. That is why the police temporarily blocked the site

Comment: That's a lot of coverage if "keeping it quiet was the plan all along". ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar And note that the first link leads to *De Telegraaf* which is (one of)  the largest daily newspapers in the country :)

Comment: @CommonGuy Well De Telegraaf is also the most sensationalist. Also the other news outlets you linked to are not my first choices for reliable information. Note that the article from Hart van Nederland writes the birds had no internal bleeding at all and speculated about poisoning whereas rtlnieuws seems to exclude poisoning while saying internal bleeding was found.

Comment: @11684 Do you want to say they all invented the story?

Comment: No but they might exaggerate and/or mix up the details (which they did).

Comment: in fact there can't have been 5G antennas as there is no 5G network in the Netherlands.

Comment: @jwenting There could be 5G antennas for testing purposes (as quoted in the question).

Comment: @CommonGuy AFAIK no 5G hardware has been certified in the Netherlands, so no testing in public places would be allowed.

Comment: The "Dieren" in "Dierenambulance" means "animal(s)", so that's where "Animal Ambulance" come from elsewhere in the translation.

Comment: You're citing 4 well known tabloid sources who often make up their own truths... Not really reputable sources especially if it's the combination of those 4. (Who often work together to form a mob-rule against anything new like climate change or new technology).

Answer (score 8):

1. > Is it true that hundreds of birds have died in this park?

   Yes.
2. > If it is true, has a cause been positively determined?

   There appears to still be no certainty about the cause.

---

> Both the Natural History Museum in Rotterdam and the Wageningen
> Bioveterinary Research Laboratory in Lelystad think they have solved
> the riddle of the 'massive starvation deaths', this autumn in the
> center of The Hague. However, they come to totally different
> conclusions. They ate poisonous yew, says the laboratory. No, says the
> museum: they flew themselves to pieces.

Source: [https://www.volkskrant.nl/nieuws-achtergrond/mysterieuze-spreeuwensterfte-nee-ze-vlogen-zich-te-pletter~b6e09555/](https://www.volkskrant.nl/nieuws-achtergrond/mysterieuze-spreeuwensterfte-nee-ze-vlogen-zich-te-pletter%7Eb6e09555/)

Other references:

1. https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2018/12/28/onderzoek-spreeuwensterfte-door-bloedingen-a3127202
2. [https://www.ad.nl/den-haag/spreeuwen-niet-overleden-door-taxus-maar-door-botsingen~a06e7b5f/](https://www.ad.nl/den-haag/spreeuwen-niet-overleden-door-taxus-maar-door-botsingen%7Ea06e7b5f/)
3. [https://www.ad.nl/den-haag/laboratorium-bevestigt-spreeuwensterfte-door-natuurlijke-vergiftiging-br-via-de-taxusplant~a1d3218f/](https://www.ad.nl/den-haag/laboratorium-bevestigt-spreeuwensterfte-door-natuurlijke-vergiftiging-br-via-de-taxusplant%7Ea1d3218f/)

Comment: I'd trust the BRL over some museum :) And of course the one does not exclude the other. A poisoned bird may inadvertently hit something when flying.